# variable takes extra characters once exit the while loop, C language using malloc()

Tags: c, string, while-loop, scope, malloc

I solved this problem by using realloc(), which is more brief and easier to understand.
Though using malloc() is taking detour, it still helps to enhance my coding logic.
Below is the realloc() version.

```
char* getInput(char* inputStr)
{
   int count = 1;
   char *ch;

   do{
       count++;
       fgets(ch, 2, stdin);  //ch stores 1 char from user each time
       inputStr = realloc(inputStr, (count+1)* sizeof(char));
       strcat(inputStr, ch);   
       printf("in do inputStr=%s\n", inputStr);
   }while(ch[0] != '\n');
   inputStr[count] = '\0';
   printf("in while inputStr=%s\n", inputStr);
return inputStr;
}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Original question:
I'm new to C, and I'm in trouble with `malloc` function.
In my program, the user need to input a arbitrary long string, if there exists a space in the string, then string variable command will take the first part of the input string, variable `filename` will take the second part. e.g:
Input- read mydiary.txt 
`inputStr`'s data is `read`, command's data is `mydiary.txt`
I wrote a separate `getComd.c` file, the command will just take the first part of the `inputStr`, however, when I put functions `getComd` together with `getInput`, `getComd` will copy the whole `getInput` string, with the extra filename.

I've put some `printf` inside the code to help tracing.
I doubt if there is something to do with the variable scope, but I cannot detect the real problem.
Could anyone help me to explain what happened in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* getInput(void);
char* getComd(char* inputStr, char* comd);

int main(){
   char* inputStr;
   char* command;
   char* filename;

   printf("Input- ");
   inputStr = getInput();
   printf("inputStr=%s\n", inputStr);
   command = getComd(inputStr, command);
   return 0;
}

char* getInput()
{
   char* str;
   char* _str;
   int i = 1;   // 1 is for the first char to take;
   str = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));  // i+1 is for the '\0'
   str[i-1] = '\0';

   while( '\n' != ( str[i-1] = getchar() ) ) 
   {
      i++;
      _str = malloc(i*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(_str, str);
      free(str);

      str = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(str, _str);
      str[i-1] = '\0';
      free(_str);
   }
return str;
}

char* getComd(char* inputStr, char* comd)
{
   comd=NULL;
   char* _comd=NULL;
   int i = 1;   //  1 is to take 1st input char;
   comd = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));  // i+1 is for the '\0'
   printf("enter while loop\n");
   while(  ( comd[i-1] = inputStr[i-1] ) != ' '){
      i++;
      _comd = malloc(i*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(_comd, comd);
      free(comd);

      comd = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(comd, _comd);
      comd[i-1] = '\0';
      free(_comd);
      printf("comd=%s\n", comd);
   }
printf("outside while loop, comd=%s\n", comd);
return comd;
}
```

Below is the independent getComd.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main(){
   char* inputStr="hello world";
   char* comd = NULL;
   char* _comd = NULL;
   int i = 1;   // 1 is for the first char to take;
   comd = malloc( (i+1)*sizeof(char) );  // i+1 is for the '\0'
   printf("enter while loop\n");
   while(  ( comd[i-1] = inputStr[i-1] ) != ' '){
      i++;
      _comd = malloc(i*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(_comd, comd);
      free(comd);

      comd = malloc((i+1)*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(comd,  _comd);
      comd[i-1] = '\0';
      free(_comd);
      printf("comd=%s\n", comd);
   }
printf("outside the while, comd=%s\n", comd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing the `malloc/strcpy/free` twice? I think the second one was supposed to be after the loop, to add 1 for the null.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use `malloc/strcpy/free`, you can use `realloc()` to do it all in one step.

Comment: one is for taking the whole input, the other one is to let variable command take data. inputStr and command are two variables with arbitrary length.

Comment: I'm talking about `strcpy(_str, str);` followed by `strcpy(str, _str)`.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. The logic of the while loop is not reasonable. Using malloc only is taking a detour. And I solved this problem by using realloc.